# Using the new google cloud translate to translate an entire page/site

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, google-translate, google-translation-api

Now that Google have dumped their website translator and are no longer using JS for their translation, how can we go about using their tools to translate all the text on a page or website?
I had the idea of using JS to autoselect any non-blank text on the page and hit up google cloud translate and bulk translate the page, however that doesn't seem available any more.

Everything I see is geared toward translating single phrases/words. Which in MVC means having to have custom razor calls all through the code.

Comment: Are you talking about [integrating with the Cloud Translation API from you own site](https://cloud.google.com/translate/markup) or calling the API to translate any site?  In the latter case, the recommended maximum length for each request is 5K characters and with Cloud Translation - Advanced, the maximum number of code points for a single request is 30K ([Quotas](https://cloud.google.com/translate/quotas)). This is a lot and should be enough to translate most of pages.

Comment: I'm talking about using it to translate my own site, but do all the page at once. None of the google examples or documentation I could find do this, it's always a string by string method which will add a huge amount of time to dev.

Comment: I am still not sure that we are talking about the same thing here. But, indeed, to translate your own page with the **Translation API Markup**, at most, you can translate [For entire documents or web page](https://cloud.google.com/translate/markup#for_entire_documents_or_web_page).

Comment: That link is for a page using markup to describe a page that has already been translated by the previous methods isn't it? Not to actually translate the page.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I was way off, sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You could upload your pages to GCS and then use the Cloud Translation API Advanced batchTranslateText method (<= 1000 files and <= 100M Unicode codepoints) ([Client libraries Ref](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/libraries/v3/overview-v3), [REST API Ref](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/rest/v3/projects.locations/batchTranslateText#InputConfig)).

In the [InputConfig](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/reference/rest/v3/projects.locations/batchTranslateText#inputconfig), you can specify:

- mimeType `text/plain` or `text/html` (default). For `.tsv` files, `text/html` is used if mimeType is missing.
- gcsSource: Required. Google Cloud Storage location for the source input. This can be a single file (for example, gs://translation-test/input.tsv) or a wildcard (for example, gs://translation-test/*).

Comment: This has to be dynamic on-the-fly translation as the page text will be changing.